# changing format of a df and removing undesired char

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, currency

I have the following dataframe:

```
Name             Price  
AG              €26.74
BAE             €0.25
C&C             Nan
CRH             €30.57
```

I would like to remove the euro sign from the numbers and turn the column price to numeric.

Desired output

```
Name            Price   
AG              26.74
BAE             0.25
C&C             Nan
CRH             30.57
```

What i was thinking of is :

```
df['Price'].map(lambda x:str(x)[1:])
```

But that would modify the `Nan` value , to `an`, and I would like to remain the rows with the Nan values.

Also I thought :

```
df['Price'].split("€")[1]
```

but outputs

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Is there a better way to obtain the desired output remaining the Nan values?

Comment: it shoud be `df['Price'].str.split("€")[1]` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [27]: df.Price = pd.to_numeric(df.Price.str.replace(r'[€]', ''), errors='coerce')

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
        Name  Price
0         AG  26.74
1        BAE   0.25
2  C&C Group    NaN
3        CRH  30.57

In [29]: df.dtypes
Out[29]:
Name      object
Price    float64   # <-----
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it: `pd.to_numeric` + `str.replace`.

```
df.Price = pd.to_numeric(df.Price.str.replace('[^\d.]', ''), errors='coerce')

print(df.Price)
0    26.74
1     0.25
2      NaN
3    30.57
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

The regular expression `[^\d.]` removes anything that is not a valid symbol in a currency value.

If you want to consider other representations (such as exponents and -ve numbers), use `[^\d.e-]` instead.